# importing modules from a folder in portable python

Tags: python, module

i've python in a usb stick and i'm designing a [recursive descent parser](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Recursive_descent_parser).

the main script is `recursive.py` which is run by following code from command prompt.

```
python.exe compiler\recursive.py<compiler\rd_input
```

my directory structure is

```
python.exe
compiler\
    recursive.py
    rd_input
```

in my code i'm generating a python script with 3 functions.

```
compiler\   
    recursive_header.py
```

which i need to import in the main script `recursive.py` later.

i've tried `import recursive_header` and `import compiler\recursive_header` and `import compiler/recursive_header`
it's showing the error

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "compiler\recursive.py", line 74, in <module>
    import recursive_header
ImportError: No module named recursive_header
```

i've tried the solution given [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/279237/import-a-module-from-a-folder). but same error.

also tried

```
import sys
sys.path.append('/compiler')
import recursive_header
```

here error numbers increased mentioning some about `sys`.

how can i import compiler\recursive_header.py in my script.

Comment: sorry silly mistake. i was creating the file with a little typo:`open('compiler/recusrive_header.py','a')` corrected that and then import is success with just `import recusrive_header`.

Answer (score 2):

You need an empty `__init__.py` file in `\compiler` (to tell python that `compiler` is a module) and then do:

```
import compiler.recursive_header
```

*However* If you are **generating** the module try generating it in a different module and loading that, i.e have the following structure:

```
python.exe
compiler
   __init__.py
   recursive.py
compiled
   __init__.py
   compiled_file_1.py
   compiled_file_2.py
```

For more detail on why this works the way it does see [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6507896/python-how-to-load-a-module-twice)

Comment: same error is showing.

Comment: Just to be clear - are you *generating* the python code from recursive.py?

Comment: yes. as per recursive descent parser we have to create the functions based on the grammar provided. different recursive_header.py files for different grammars.

Comment: by the way thanks. i didn't know about `__init__.py`, but learnt it today. i've solved my code.

Comment: OK - the problem is **probably** that the python interpreter won't load the same package twice, even if you change the code - it will use the old `*.pyc` files, you will need to create a new package and load it every time you generate the code. I've edited my answer. If it solves your problem please accept, if it doesn't please post your own answer :)

Comment: it's not having a problem. the script is generating the file, compiling it during the import and using the functions nicely.

Comment: I'm glad, that's what I thought should happen :) . It's because your `python.exe compiler\recursive.py<compiler\rd_input` command is not importing a module.