# What happens when a module is imported twice?

Tags: python, module

I have a doubt that I would like to get cleared up.

Consider the following module named `ex_1.py`:

```
print("Hello, I'm ex_1")
def greet(name):
 print("Hello, "+name+" nice to meet you! ")
```

Now consider another file called `1_client_ex_1.py` that will import `ex_1.py` module.

```
import ex_1.py
```

Now when I execute this file, I get the output as :

```
Hello, I'm ex_1
```

As expected.

But when I change to `1_client_ex_1.py` to:

```
import ex_1.py
import ex_1.py
```

and execute it, it still prints only `Hello, I'm ex_1` once. Shouldn't it print it twice?

Comment: the behavior is correct

Answer (score 78, accepted):

Nothing, if a module has already been imported, it's not loaded again.

You will simply get a reference to the module that has already been imported (it will come from `sys.modules`).

To get a list of the modules that have already been imported, you can look up `sys.modules.keys()` (note that `urllib`here imports a *lot* of other modules):

```
>>> import sys
>>> print len(sys.modules.keys())
44
>>> print sys.modules.keys()
['copy_reg', 'sre_compile', '_sre', 'encodings', 'site', '__builtin__', 'sysconfig', '__main__', 'encodings.encodings', 'abc', 'posixpath', '_weakrefset', 'errno', 'encodings.codecs', 'sre_constants', 're', '_abcoll', 'types', '_codecs', 'encodings.__builtin__', '_warnings', 'genericpath', 'stat', 'zipimport', '_sysconfigdata', 'warnings', 'UserDict', 'encodings.utf_8', 'sys', 'virtualenvwrapper', '_osx_support', 'codecs', 'readline', 'os.path', 'sitecustomize', 'signal', 'traceback', 'linecache', 'posix', 'encodings.aliases', 'exceptions', 'sre_parse', 'os', '_weakref']
>>> import urllib
>>> print len(sys.modules.keys())
70
>>> print sys.modules.keys()
['cStringIO', 'heapq', 'base64', 'copy_reg', 'sre_compile', '_collections', '_sre', 'functools', 'encodings', 'site', '__builtin__', 'sysconfig', 'thread', '_ssl', '__main__', 'operator', 'encodings.encodings', '_heapq', 'abc', 'posixpath', '_weakrefset', 'errno', '_socket', 'binascii', 'encodings.codecs', 'urllib', 'sre_constants', 're', '_abcoll', 'collections', 'types', '_codecs', 'encodings.__builtin__', '_struct', '_warnings', '_scproxy', 'genericpath', 'stat', 'zipimport', '_sysconfigdata', 'string', 'warnings', 'UserDict', 'struct', 'encodings.utf_8', 'textwrap', 'sys', 'ssl', 'virtualenvwrapper', '_osx_support', 'codecs', 'readline', 'os.path', 'strop', '_functools', 'sitecustomize', 'socket', 'keyword', 'signal', 'traceback', 'urlparse', 'linecache', 'itertools', 'posix', 'encodings.aliases', 'time', 'exceptions', 'sre_parse', 'os', '_weakref']
>>> import urllib #again!
>>> print len(sys.modules.keys()) #has not loaded any additional modules
70
```

Let's give it a whirl:

```
import sys
>>> sys.modules["foo"] = "bar"  # Let's pretend we imported a module named "foo", which is a string.
>>> print __import__("foo")
bar  # Not a module, that's my string!
```

As you can see, if a module is found un `sys.modules`, you'll just get a new reference to it. That's it.

---

Note that  this means that **modules should be designed so as to not have side effects (such as printing stuff) when they're imported**.

Reloading modules, outside of an interactive session, is usually not a very good practice either (although it has its use cases) - the other answers will detail how you'd do this.

Comment: "Nothing, if a module has already been imported, it's not loaded again." Python (at least 2.7) absolutely does not guarantee this. Particularly if, for example, multiple threads end up importing the same module.

Answer (score 8):

A Python script will load a module only once. To reload it, use:

```
reload()      # Python 2
```

and

```
imp.reload()  # Python 3
```

Answer (score 5):

Module is only loaded the first time the `import` statement is executed. See also [`reload()`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#reload) and [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6507896/python-how-to-load-a-module-twice). You can examine `sys.modules` to find out which modules have already been loaded.

Answer (score 1):

About the above answers, yes python won't import it twice and it will only examine `sys.modules` first. but this operation can be costly when we are talking about too many imports for the same library.
you can check it [here](https://wiki.python.org/moin/PythonSpeed/PerformanceTips#Import_Statement_Overhead) in python wiki.

you can check my experiment here screenshot

[image: 2]