# python package best practice: managing imports

Tags: python, pypi, python-packaging

Coming from R, I'm trying to wrap my head around the package system in python.

**My question (in short) is: what is the best practice for managing external library imports?**

Suppose I have a package (call it `pointless`) with the following directory structure.

```
pointless/
    setup.py
    ...etc
    pointless/
        __init__.py
        module1.py
        module2.py
```

And suppose both `module1` and `module2` had the header:

```
from __future__ import division
import numpy as np
...
```

My issue is that when I `import pointless` I get a double-whammy of `np` and `division` in both `pointless.module1` and `pointless.module2`. There has to be a better way?

#### EDIT

Apologies if that wasn't clear. It bugs me that when I run (ipython):

```
>>> import pointless
>>> pointless.module1.<TAB>
pointless.module1.np
pointless.module.division
...

>>> pointless.module2.<TAB>
pointless.module1.np
pointless.module.division
...
```

I can see the `np` namespace in both modules, which seems messy and way overkill.

Is there a way I can "*centralize*" my external library imports so that I don't see them in every module? Or am I missing something?

Comment: I'm sorry but you get what?

Comment: What is the problem you are trying to fix?

Comment: all the import statement does is bind a name into the importing module's namespace. it's only the first ever import of a module that actually loads it. so there is no overkill.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is related to this question: [what happens when i import module twice in python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19077381/what-happens-when-i-import-module-twice-in-python). Long story short: If you import a module twice, it is loaded only once, so your example is not problematic at all.