# Real-life module reloading in Python?

Tags: python, python-3.x, module, reload

I am going through a book on Python which spends a decent time on module reloading, but does not explain well when it would be useful.

Hence, I am wondering, what are some real-life examples of when such technique becomes handy?

That is, I understand what reloading does. I am trying to understand how one would use it in real world.

**Edit:**

I am not suggesting that this technique is not useful. Instead, I am trying to learn more about its applications as it seems quite cool.

**Also, I think people who marked this question as duplicate took no time to actually read the question and how it is different from the proposed duplicate. 
I am not asking HOW TO reload a module in Python. I already know how to do that. I am asking WHY one would want to reload a module in Python in real life. There is a huge difference in nature of these questions.**

Comment: Apparently this person needed it: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/437589/how-do-i-unload-reload-a-python-module

Comment: I mean using the `from imp import reload` and doing something like `reload(module_name)`

Comment: @MadPhysicist Yes, I know. I just realized that. I (mistakenly) thought you were asking [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19077381/what-happens-when-i-import-module-twice-in-python).

Comment: @ChristianDean no problem.

Comment: The question is about _why_ to do reloading, not _how_ to do reloading. I do not see how it is a duplicate. I propose to reopen it.

Comment: @DYZ precisely! Whoever marked it as duplicate clearly misread or misunderstood the question!

Answer (score 3):

Module reloading (also known as "hot-swapping") is commonly used in long-running systems, such as telephone switch software, that cannot be shut down for maintenance without causing costly service interruption. Such systems are upgraded piece-wise, one module at a time. For example, hot-swapping is natively supported at the implementation level by [Erlang](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/erlang).

Python systems rarely run for long time. Real-life module reloading in Python does not seem to be of major importance.

EDIT: As @Aaron suggested, module reloading is used in some Python IDEs to facilitate module development.

Comment: Some IDEs (spyder) provide module re-loading mechanisms within their shell to make developing those modules easier.

Comment: @Aaron True. I interpreted "real-life" as "industrial use." One may argue forever if this includes IDEs.

Comment: This is an overly simplistic and a little narrow. There are plenty of reasons to reload modules Django is a splendid example of long-running web servers that require it. See the duplicate answer for more detail

Answer (score 0):

As an appendix to DYZ's answer, I use module reloading when analysing large data in interactive Python interpreter.

Loading and preprocessing of the data takes some time and I prefer to keep them in the memory (in a module BTW) rather than restart the interpreter every time I change something in my modules.