# Why variable value change

Tags: python, python-3.x, variables, import, module

I have file abcd.py

```
a=9
def funn():
    print("A")
```

I import it two times

```
>>> import abcd as ss
>>> ss.a
9
>>> import abcd as  qq
>>> qq.a
9
```

But When I change value of `a` from `ss` imported file, `qq` import file value of `a` is automatically change.

```
>>> ss.a=4
>>> ss.a
4
>>> qq.a
4
```

Comment: Check [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19077381/what-happens-when-i-import-module-twice-in-python) question, it explains what happens when you import a module twice.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Python doesn't actually re-import a module that it's already imported. So when you do

```
import abcd as qq
```

you're simply creating another name for the `abcd` module, which you've already imported as `ss`. So `ss.a` and `qq.a` are just synonyms for the same integer object.

You may find this article helpful: [Facts and myths about Python names and values](http://nedbatchelder.com/text/names.html), which was written by SO veteran Ned Batchelder.