# Can I recover a python function I mistakenly deleted in a Jupyter notebook?

Tags: python, python-3.x, function, matplotlib, jupyter-notebook

I imported `matplotlib.pyplot` as `plt`, then mistakenly defined a variable with the the function `matplotlib.pyplot.xticks` function name (i.e. `plt.xticks = ...` instead of `plt.xticks(...)`) in a Jupyter notebook. Then I tried to undo the definition with `del plt.xticks` and it removed the variable, but also the function. I tried reimporting matplotlib, but still plt.xticks is not there:

```
plt.xticks

AttributeError: module 'matplotlib.pyplot' has no attribute 'xticks'
```

In other notebooks the command works, even after reimporting the library. In this specific notebook I can get around the problem by `import matplotlib`. Is there another way around?

Comment: `import matplotlib.pyplot as plt` didn't work? That's just a fancy assignment statement, and it should overwrite whatever value `plt` is bound to with the module.

Comment: If you import something again that's already been imported, [nothing happens](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19077396/4739755). You can use [`importlib.reload`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/importlib.html#importlib.reload) to force a re-assignment/re-read of the module contents however. Edit: To clarify, this _will not_ fix the OP's problem however. Re-definitions of names will remain.

Answer (score 1):

I did the same thing once, restarting the kernel did the trick.