# Python - Loading an arbitrary settings file (JSON/YAML) and making it available to submodules

Tags: python, json, parameters, yaml, settings

I have a large codebase where all settings & constants are stored inside a `settings.py` file, that gets imported in various places. I want to be able to import an arbitrary `.yml` file instead, with the filename given at run-time to the executable `main.py`.

It's easy to change `settings` to load a `.yml` file; but of course I can't pass it an arbitrary filename from `main`, such that it will remember wherever else that `settings` gets imported.

I tried to think of a few solutions:

1. Modify `main` so that the first thing it does is copy the arbitrary yaml file, into the default place the yaml file will be loaded from (ugly)
2. Import the settings in `main.py`, and change references from `import settings` to `import main` (circular imports)
3. Use `os` to set an environment variable `SETTINGS_FILE=some_file.yml`, that later gets read by the `settings` submodule (somewhat ugly...)
4. Refactor the entire codebase to pass around a `settings` class instead of a module (a lot of work)

I feel like I'm generally thinking of this all in a stupid way, and that there must be a better way (although I couldn't find anything by search)... what am I missing?

**EDIT:**

I had no idea but apparently this works...

$ cat settings.py

```
setting = 1
```

$ cat other_module.py

```
import settings
print(settings.setting)
```

$ cat main.py

```
import settings
print(settings.setting)
settings.setting = 2
import other_module
```

$ python main.py

```
1
2
```

Comment: Why not triggering the loading of the YAML file in `main` and then put it in a variable in `settings`?

Comment: @flyx Oh my goodness, I had no idea you could do this. So once `settings` is modified within `main`, if it is imported in another module (itself imported by main), the modifications to `settings` made from within `main` still remain. I guess importing it from the other module doesn't trigger a true "reimport"...? Thanks, didn't realise that...!

Comment: [See here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19077381/what-happens-when-a-module-is-imported-twice)