# calling modules hierarchy python

Tags: python, module

in python when I need to use a function I have to import the entire module or the specific function in the module. 
What if I import directly a module and the same module is imported from another module that  I import later? 
Just for example in a hypothetical `myapp.py` there are theese three rows:

```
import module1
import module2
import module3
```

in `module1.py` there are other importing instructions like

```
import mymodule
import module2
import module4
```

The chain of import modules can ben longer than that in a regular application.
If I well understood when I run `myapp.py` the interpreter runs the first line `import module1` and then opens `module1.py` and start processing it, starting from its first line `import mymodule` then the second `import module2` and so on. But when returning to second line of `myapp.py` it has to process

```
import module2
```

that has been already processed!
What does happens in that situation?
I have to be aware of all the duplicating coding calls or simply python itself discard the second `import module2` call because he knows it has already done the `import`?
In big (and usual) apps, it's common to use very large amount of libraries (modules): how can I check all the cross calls between modules and secondly should I worry about it?
Regards, Marco

Answer (score 0):

sorry for the noise....I've found that this question was already answered in `https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19077381/what-happens-when-a-module-is-imported-twice`