# After re importing module why variable in original module not showing their initial value

Tags: python, import, module

```
# code of foo.py

var = 7
```

```
#code of foo1.py

import foo

print(foo.var) # it prints 7 

foo.var = 9  

print(foo.var) # it prints 9


#from "foo" reload(var)
import foo #reimporting module

print(foo.var) # still it prints 9 instead of 7 why?
```

Comment: Modules in python are always imported only once.

Comment: you cannot do like that, afaik, you need to run the python file again.

Answer (score 1):

The reason is that second `import foo` doesn't effect. See this question: [What happens when a module is imported twice?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19077381/what-happens-when-a-module-is-imported-twice).

Comment: Since the linked question doesn't have it, the python docs on this can be found here: [The Module Cache](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/import.html#the-module-cache)

Answer (score 0):

In python modules are singleton, meaning every import statement return the same instance of a module. As a consequence, any mutation of a module is visible to every scope that import this module.

https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/modules.html#more-on-modules