# Why is executed only one module import instead of 2?

Tags: python, import, module

I suppose to have 3 files in the folder `project` as showed following:

```
project
 |- module_b.py
 |- script_B1.py
 |- script_B2.py
```

### Content of 3 python files

The content of `module_b.py` is:

```
print("Inside module_b")
```

The content of `script_B1.py` is:

```
import module_b
print("Inside script_B1")
```

The content of `script_B2.py` is:

```
import module_b
import script_B1
print("Inside script_B2")
```

### Output of execution of 2 scripts

The output of the execution of `script_B1.py` is:

```
Inside module_b
Inside script_B1
```

The output of `script_B2.py` is:

```
Inside module_b
Inside script_B1
Inside script_B2
```

### Question about the output of `script_B2.py`

In the execution of `script_B2.py` the module `module_b.py` is imported first by `script_B2.py` and after by `script_B1.py`. So I was thinking that the output of the execution of `script_B2.py` would be:

```
Inside module_b
Inside module_b
Inside script_B1
Inside script_B2
```

My question is: why the output of execution of `script_B2.py` contains only one string `Inside module_b`?

---

**EDIT**:
I have modified the file `script_B2.py` adding 2 prints of the list `sys.modules.keys()`:

```
import sys
import module_b
print(sys.modules.keys())
import script_B1
print(sys.modules.keys())
print("Inside script_B2")
```

By these prints I can see that, after the `import module_b` inside the file `script_B2.py`, the list `sys.modules.keys()` contains the element `module_b`.
This avoid the execution of the code of `module_a.py` when it is imported by `script_B1.py`.

Comment: When one module attempts to import another, the cache for the main module is searched first. If the module has already been imported, it is not imported again.

Comment: You could look at `sys.path`. Once a module is in `sys.path.keys()`, python knows the module is already imported and doesn't do it again.

Comment: It would be bad if modules were re-imported. Not only would all of their initialization code run again, its contained functions would get a new global namespace. Any global variable used by the module wouldn't really be global any more. If you ran the same function from different imports, that function would see a different global (that is, module) namespace.

Comment: @tdelaney My real problem is to avoid  `all of their initialization code run again`. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A module that has already been imported is not loaded again.

This question is a duplicate of this question: [What happens when a module is imported twice?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19077381/what-happens-when-a-module-is-imported-twice)

Comment: Thank you. From [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19077381/what-happens-when-a-module-is-imported-twice) I have learned that `sys.modules.keys()` is the list where is contained the name `module_b` and in this case the second import is not executed.